# Published node not appearing in library

Tags: node-red

Has anyone got any ideas why the node I published on npm ([node-red-contrib-udmx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-udmx)) is not appearing in the [Node Red library](https://flows.nodered.org/)?

The package file includes:

```
"node-red": {
  "nodes": {
    "udmx": "udmx.js"
  }
},
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious - just can't see it!

Answer (score 0):

The `package.json` looks right (the important bit is `node-red` in the keywords and a valid license and a README.md).

The Node-RED flow library depends on http://libraries.io which can take a little while to index new nodes. (Your node wasn't there when I looked)

Give it a few hours and if it still hasn't shown up you can sign into https://flows.nodered.org (see login with github link in the top right hand corner) and request an update.

If it still doesn't show up then you can post to the Slack team (linked from the Node-RED homepage) and Nick will be able to have a look (when he has time)

Comment: Thanks for looking, @hardillb. I published it yesterday, but will try a little more patience first....

Comment: It's not showing up on librairies.io and their front page says raise a bug if it's not showing up